# Returning function output

Tags: r

I am trying to run this function and trying to obtain output. Inputs are in vector form and response of the function in fact include a vector and not a scalar. I tried this code but its not working. I am new to R and your assistance will be highly appreciated. Following is the code

```
park91a <- function(xx) {
  x1 <- xx[1]
  x2 <- xx[2]
  x3 <- xx[3]
  x4 <- xx[4]

  term1a <- x1/2
  term1b <- sqrt(abs(1 + (x2+x3^2)*x4/(x1^2))) - 1
  term1 <- term1a * term1b

  term2a <- x1 + 3*x4
  term2b <- exp(1 + sin(x3))
  term2 <- term2a * term2b

  real <- term1 + term2
  return(real)
}

data <- read.csv("TRANSISTORDATA.txt")
mydata <- na.omit(data)
mydata
inputs <- mydata[1:10,1:4] 
y <- mydata[,7]
y <- y[1:10]
xx<- inputs
xx
xx <- c(inputs)
park91a(xx)
```

inputs include data like this

```
      x1    x2    x3    x4
1   0.21 -0.26  0.23 -0.21
2  -0.19  0.18  0.22  0.21
3  -0.19 -0.08 -0.28 -0.28
4   0.19 -0.25  0.28  0.28
5  -0.28  0.25 -0.22 -0.21
6  -0.22  0.21  0.17  0.16
7  -0.22 -0.12  0.27 -0.25
8   0.11  0.23 -0.27  0.24
9  -0.19 -0.19 -0.19  0.24
10  0.17  0.21  0.19 -0.24
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Please put it in your question, i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52184819/edit

Comment: Right off the bat there's a problem with you function, since your input is a matrix, but you're subsetting for a vector (i.e., should be `xx[1,]`, if you're trying to get the first row). Since it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, it's difficult to say how you need to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a matrix, then `xx[1]` will be 0.21, `xx[2]` will be -0.19, and it will carry on down the first column in that fashion. If you wish to calculate for the whole columns (I assume this is the intention given the column names and names in the function. then you will need to edit the first lines of the function, such as:

```
x1 <- xx[,1]
x2 <- xx[,2]
x3 <- xx[,3]
x4 <- xx[,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not gave your desired output. So your question is not totally clear to me. First of all I reconstructed your data:

```
inputs <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"    x1    x2    x3    x4
   0.21 -0.26  0.23 -0.21
  -0.19  0.18  0.22  0.21
  -0.19 -0.08 -0.28 -0.28
   0.19 -0.25  0.28  0.28
  -0.28  0.25 -0.22 -0.21
  -0.22  0.21  0.17  0.16
  -0.22 -0.12  0.27 -0.25
   0.11  0.23 -0.27  0.24
  -0.19 -0.19 -0.19  0.24
  0.17  0.21  0.19 -0.24")
```

Eventually you want something like this:

```
within(inputs, {
  term1a <- x1/2
  term1b <- sqrt(abs(1 + (x2+x3^2)*x4/(x1^2))) - 1
  term1 <- term1a * term1b

  term2a <- x1 + 3*x4
  term2b <- exp(1 + sin(x3))
  term2 <- term2a * term2b

  real <- term1 + term2
})
```

result:

```
#       x1    x2    x3    x4       real      term2   term2b term2a         term1       term1b term1a
# 1   0.21 -0.26  0.23 -0.21 -1.3910343 -1.4340132 3.414317  -0.42  0.0429788836  0.409322701  0.105
# 2  -0.19  0.18  0.22  0.21  1.4377575  1.4877264 3.381196   0.44 -0.0499689622  0.525989076 -0.095
# 3  -0.19 -0.08 -0.28 -0.28 -2.1243796 -2.1237920 2.061934  -1.03 -0.0005876561  0.006185854 -0.095
# 4   0.19 -0.25  0.28  0.28  3.6507163  3.6910628 3.583556   1.03 -0.0403465463 -0.424700487  0.095
# 5  -0.28  0.25 -0.22 -0.21 -1.9113789 -1.9886573 2.185338  -0.91  0.0772783929 -0.551988521 -0.140
# 6  -0.22  0.21  0.17  0.16  0.7998736  0.8370334 3.219359   0.26 -0.0371597771  0.337816156 -0.110
# 7  -0.22 -0.12  0.27 -0.25 -3.4554087 -3.4427557 3.549233  -0.97 -0.0126529657  0.115026961 -0.110
# 8   0.11  0.23 -0.27  0.24  1.8185544  1.7279556 2.081874   0.83  0.0905987637  1.647250250  0.055
# 9  -0.19 -0.19 -0.19  0.24  1.2732947  1.1927515 2.250475   0.53  0.0805431677 -0.847822818 -0.095
# 10  0.17  0.21  0.19 -0.24 -1.8039939 -1.8058328 3.283332  -0.55  0.0018389314  0.021634487  0.085
```

or this:

```
inputs$real <- with(inputs, 
  x1/2   *    (sqrt(abs(1 + (x2+x3^2)*x4/(x1^2))) - 1) +
  (x1 + 3*x4)  *   exp(1 + sin(x3))
)
```

Comment: Its really very nice of you to address my problem. Actually, the calculation of the function is supposed to be done by taking 1st row (i.e. one value against each column), and one value is obtained as output against each row. Therefore, the output will be a vector of dimension 10X1.

Comment: If you dont need the other interim results `term1a` ... `term2` then the second variant covers your needs (eventuall without assigning the result, i.e. without `inputs$real <-`). BTW: calculations in `R` are normally vectorized.